# MacOS High Sierra and X11 forwarding

Tags: macos, x11-forwarding

All,

I do have linux servers which do not have GUI installed and sometimes I just need to use graphical applications, such as installers. So the option is to use X11 forwarding. My question is how X11 forwarding is used with MacOS High Sierra today.  What options or applications you do use? On windows I would probably use Xming or similar but are such server also available on MacOS? I know about XQuartz, but I'm reluctant to install it.

Answer (score 9):

XQuartz is standard.   It used to come bundled with the OS, but Apple removed it back around Mavericks.  It generally works great.

You want to use:

```
ssh -Y [remote_server]
```

and you may have to add to your `$HOME/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host [remote_server]
   ForwardX11 yes
   ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint to use -Y instead of -X :)